# Windows spell check and delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, spell-checking

Is there a spell check in Windows (like in Mac OS X)? If yes, is there any way to use on a richedit on delphi 7?

I've been trying to find that answer on the internet but so far no answer.

code is appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Built in Spell Check in Windows.   Applications are required to implement there own.   When it  comes to Delphi you have several options, some of which include:

- [Addict Spell Check](http://www.addictivesoftware.com/)
- [HunSpell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/)
- [LS Spell](http://www.luziusschneider.com/SpellerHome.htm)
- [Express Spell checker](http://devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExSpellChecker/)

Addict is one of the more complete solutions, but I have used HunSpell successfully where Addict was not available. Addict and DevExpress are both compiled into the application.

Comment: hmmm. they are all external DLLs. I was trying to find something that doesn't add DLLs and other files to my app (an app that is a standalone exe, portable and supper fast). I guess it can't be done then. thanks tho for the information

Comment: I've never done it and there may be pitfalls, but there are ways to bundle a dll inside an .exe (as a resource perhaps?) and then extract it at runtime if needed...) These days, you might fall afoul of various security features though...

Comment: Addict is not an external DLL.

Comment: +1 for addict, and it's not a DLL.  It works with lots of 3rd-party editor VCLs.  And it can even pull custom dictionary words from the MSOffice dictionary.  Lots of free international dictionaries available, even UK English vs. USA  English.